# Architectural Description Language (ADLs) usage?

Tags: argument-dependent-lookup

Im doing a project for Software Architecture Module and have to create one of my 'Views' using an ADL. While I've been doing some research into the various ADL's I have found out that most of them have not been updated within the last 5 years......they call seem to be dead.

Are ADL's used in the industry or is it just UML? Cause im getting the feeling that im being taught something thats not useful :s

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I've never heard of ADL.

Secondly, every technology that you use in school will be outdated by the time you graduate and get into the industry. But that's not the point. The concepts are the same, regardless of the technology. A variety of experience is the most important thing, because that will give you a large well of concepts to draw from and apply.

I hope to be using different technologies in two-or-three years than what I am using now. That is the great thing about this profession. It doesn't stagnate.

Thirdly, in a few years you are really going to regret always going by the handle "ADLNoob" in online fora. ;-)